# Name for operation similar to convolution

Tags: terminology, convolution

I have an operation, that is very similar to convolution, that I don't know the name of. I'm a programmer, not a mathematician, so I'll try to describe it as best I can.

First, a description of convolution:

1. inputs: `source` (2D array, roughly 2000x1000), `kernel` (2D array, 15x15). output will be given in an array the size of `source`
2. For every element in the output, center `kernel` over the corresponding element in `source`
3. Do elementwise multiplication between `source` and `kernel`
4. Sum the results of step 3, divide it by a number `n`, and store that in output

My operation is similar, except step 4 is replaced by:

4. Take the largest result of step 3, and store that in output

Comment: Is there a necessity for you to find what it is named as?

Comment: I want to be able to google it / find more info on it / see what properties it has.

Comment: I don't think that this operation has attracted enough attention to deserve a name. Maybe you can do something with this property: if you raise the elements of the source and kernel to a large power (assuming positive values), then perform the ordinary convolution and take the root of the same degree, you approximately get your modified convolution (if $a^n+b^n=c^n$, $c\approx\max(a, b)$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](https://www.groundai.com/project/a-bounded-p-norm-approximation-of-max-convolution-for-sub-quadratic-bayesian-inference-on-additive-factors/) describes your operation as a ***"max-convolution***".

[Here](https://books.google.de/books?id=JYTLBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=%22max+convolution%22+multiplicative&source=bl&ots=tuNPxdgWhk&sig=M5GwxeLcU1GaXknkzfFra6gBL1k&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF58jJlIjcAhWJJlAKHbF7AiEQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22max%20convolution%22%20multiplicative&f=false) it is referred to as a ***"multiplicative max convolution product"***.